# pocketsphinx not getting installed in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install [pocketsphinx](/questions/tagged/pocketsphinx) package `***dependent package of textract***` on windows. I'm getting the the following error

> 'Failed to build wheel for pocketsphinx'

Has anyone come across this error. Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by downgrading python 3.6 to 3.5.